# Kafka partitions reassignment - how to rebalance partial partitions of the topic

Tags: apache-kafka

Lets say i want to re-balance the topic - `cars_data_hibrid_machines`  on my `kafka` cluster

We have 6 kafka brokers , and topic - `cars_data_hibrid_machines`   include `200` partitions , and replication `factor is 3`

In that case I will create the following `car.json`

```
{
  "version": 1,
  "topics": [
    { "topic": "cars_data_hibrid_machines" 
  ]
}
```

Then

We run the following

```
kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper $ZK_HOSTS  --topics-to-move-json-file car.json --broker-list "1,2,3,4,5,6" --generate
```

and

```
kafka-reassign-partitions.sh --zookeeper $ZK_HOSTS --reassignment-json-file reassignment.json –execute
```

now lets say we want to re balance only the first `20 partitions` of the topic - `cars_data_hibrid_machines`  on my kafka cluster

**in that case how to build the json files with topics partitions ?**

example of the topic partitions

```
Topic: cars_data_hibrid_machines   Partition: 0    Leader: 5    Replicas: 5,1,2        Isr: 5,2,1
Topic: cars_data_hibrid_machines   Partition: 1    Leader: 6    Replicas: 6,2,3        Isr: 6,2,3
Topic: cars_data_hibrid_machines   Partition: 2    Leader: 1    Replicas: 1,3,4        Isr: 4,1,3
Topic: cars_data_hibrid_machines   Partition: 3    Leader: 2    Replicas: 2,4,5        Isr: 4,5,2
Topic: cars_data_hibrid_machines   Partition: 4    Leader: 3    Replicas: 3,5,6        Isr: 5,6,3
Topic: cars_data_hibrid_machines   Partition: 5    Leader: 4    Replicas: 4,6,1        Isr: 4,6,1

.
.
.
.
.
.
```

Comment: this may help you https://labs.tabmo.io/rebalancing-kafkas-partitions-803918d8d244

Comment: What output did you get with the generate command? Why can't you remove the partitions over 20?